# Working with extended classes in PHP

Tags: php, class, methods, parameters, extend

I have 2 classes looking like this:

```
class db {

    protected $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    protected function connect() {
        $this->db = new MySQLi(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name) or die($this->db->error);
        $this->db->set_charset('utf8');
    }

}
```

and

```
class sample extends db {

    protected $js_base_dir;

    public function __construct($js_base_dir = js_dir) {
        $this->js_base_dir = $js_base_dir . "/";
    }
 ....
```

I want to use $this->db inside second class, but `__construct` in `sample` class overrides first classes construct function. How to get $this-> db inside second class? Am I doung something wrong? if yes what's proper way?

Comment: your code say that "sample is a database" .. which sounds wrong

Answer (score 3):

You can call parent class method, using `parrent::methodName()`. Similarly, you can use this to invoke parent's constructor method as well as

```
parent::__construct();
```

Usage:

```
public function __construct($js_base_dir = js_dir) {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->js_base_dir = $js_base_dir . "/";
}
```

Apart from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) read [this](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/6/10/1) article for extended explanation.

Comment: I wonder if it is proper way? Can I create new classes with that way?

Comment: @epic_syntax, Read [this](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/6/10/1) article to help clear out things.

Comment: "parent::__construct();" instead of "parent::_construct();"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function __construct($js_base_dir = js_dir) {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->js_base_dir = $js_base_dir . "/";        
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it is proper way? Can I create new classes with that way?

Comment: Nothing will change, except now your child class (Sample) will call it's parent constructor, which will initialize `$this->db`. Your calling code does NOT change.

Comment: Did you find this answer helpful?